# Rounded corners on layout

Tags: java, android, layout, rounded-corners, grid-layout

I want my `GridLayout` to have rounded corners like the 3 `Buttons` do in the below picture.  Does this require code that is different for rounding corners of Views such as `Buttons`, `TextViews`, etc?

```
gameplayGL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedcorners);
gameplayGL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
gameplayGL.getBackground().setAlpha(35);
```

roundedcorners.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Did I try my code I posted?  Yes, it gave the output of the image I posted.  Notice the layout surrounding the 3 buttons does not have rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure calling setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE) overrides the setBackgroundResource() call.

Try making a different drawable resource that is this

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners 
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

<solid
    android:color="#350000FF" />

</shape>
```

Then setting the background of the gridview to that. You may have to play with the color value to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Dur!  Should have known that!  This worked perfectly, thank you!